# deepLinkHandler vs continueUserActivity

Tags: branch.io

For architectural reasons, I would prefer not to use the deeplink handler in the appdelegate to redirect the app upon entry.

Assuming I do not care about the initial install deeplink for now, can i do this?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler {
    BOOL handledByBranch = [[Branch getInstance] continueUserActivity:userActivity];
    if (handledByBranch) {
       // REDIRECT APP TO WHERE I NEED
    }
    return handledByBranch;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch here: this may work in theory, but it is likely not the best approach and will miss some edge cases. While Branch uses Universal Links (the `continueUserActivity` method) wherever possible, there are still some situations in which your app would be launched via a URI scheme (the `openURL` method). You will need to handle both separately, and may run into some situations with undesirable side-effects.

You might find our instructions on [how to build a custom deep link router](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method) useful.

Comment: alex, i am actually already handling URL schemes seperately from a past implementation. thanks for the clarification and the link.

Comment: my concern with using the deeplinkhandler is that it seems to be triggered every single time, even when launching the app. that feels pretty intrusive.

Comment: btw, i know it is the weekend, but i am currently stuck on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198407/branch-deep-links-works-very-differently-in-different-apps-and-phones ->if you have a clue why, that would be great. just unsure if this is a default behavior or if i messed somehting up

Comment: Ahhh, yes the Branch session needs to be initiated _every_ time the app opens, otherwise very bizarre behavior will happen. However the deep link handler method shouldn't be firing every time — it sounds like something might be mixed up. You can definitely handle URL schemes from your prior implementation AND from Branch separately, though hopefully with Branch in there you won't need to ;)

Comment: Also, feel free to reach out to the Branch [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new). They're super fast, and will be able to walk through your code in depth to make sure the implementation is set up in the best possible way.